# tkinker window cannot be seen after turning into exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I compile my script using pyinstaller and found that the tkinter windows pop up and disappear very quickly, I have tried to simplified into the following code which work normally in python ide

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

sourcefilename = askopenfilename()
```

Then, I compile it in virtual environment with tkinter installed

```
(scrapytest) λ pyinstaller test.py
184 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0
185 INFO: Python: 3.8.6
186 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
187 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Tak\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts\scrapytest\Scripts\test.spec
271 INFO: UPX is available.
275 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Tak\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\Scripts\\scrapytest\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Users\\Tak\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\Scripts\\scrapytest\\Scripts']
299 INFO: checking Analysis
334 INFO: Building because C:\Users\Tak\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts\scrapytest\Scripts\test.py changed
334 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
343 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
378 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
4191 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\tak\\appdata\\local\\packages\\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\localcache\\local-packages\\python38\\scripts\\scrapytest\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
4195 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib'
6881 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
7106 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
7111 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\tak\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\scripts\scrapytest\scripts\python.exe
7155 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Tak\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts\scrapytest\Scripts\test.py
7158 INFO: Processing module hooks...
7158 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'c:\\users\\tak\\appdata\\local\\packages\\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\localcache\\local-packages\\python38\\scripts\\scrapytest\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7162 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'c:\\users\\tak\\appdata\\local\\packages\\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\localcache\\local-packages\\python38\\scripts\\scrapytest\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7598 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'c:\\users\\tak\\appdata\\local\\packages\\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\localcache\\local-packages\\python38\\scripts\\scrapytest\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7600 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'c:\\users\\tak\\appdata\\local\\packages\\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\localcache\\local-packages\\python38\\scripts\\scrapytest\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7890 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'c:\\users\\tak\\appdata\\local\\packages\\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\localcache\\local-packages\\python38\\scripts\\scrapytest\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7940 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
8739 INFO: checking Tree
9124 INFO: checking Tree
9251 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
9254 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
9258 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\tak\\appdata\\local\\packages\\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\localcache\\local-packages\\python38\\scripts\\scrapytest\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
9262 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\tak\\appdata\\local\\packages\\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\localcache\\local-packages\\python38\\scripts\\scrapytest\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
9269 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
9315 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\select.pyd
9354 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
9403 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_socket.pyd
9447 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_overlapped.pyd
9508 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
9529 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_asyncio.pyd
9562 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_queue.pyd
9632 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
9674 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_multiprocessing.pyd
9728 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
9783 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_decimal.pyd
9830 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
9872 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
9922 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
9973 WARNING: lib not found: python38.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\DLLs\_tkinter.pyd
10398 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10407 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10420 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10430 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10439 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10450 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10464 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10475 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10492 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10502 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10512 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10523 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10534 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10544 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10558 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10572 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10582 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10593 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10603 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\WINDOWS\system32\ucrtbase.dll
10657 INFO: Looking for eggs
10657 INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching...
10668 INFO: Using Python library
10669 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
10673 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Tak\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts\scrapytest\Scripts\build\test\warn-test.txt
10732 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\Tak\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts\scrapytest\Scripts\build\test\xref-test.html
10802 INFO: checking PYZ
10817 INFO: Building because toc changed
10817 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Tak\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts\scrapytest\Scripts\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz
11525 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Tak\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts\scrapytest\Scripts\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
11543 INFO: checking PKG
11555 INFO: Building because C:\Users\Tak\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts\scrapytest\Scripts\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz changed
11555 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
11615 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
11617 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\tak\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\scripts\scrapytest\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
11618 INFO: checking EXE
11630 INFO: Rebuilding EXE-00.toc because pkg is more recent
11630 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
11633 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Tak\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts\scrapytest\Scripts\build\test\test.exe
11645 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
11651 INFO: checking COLLECT
11681 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
18778 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

The exe produced wasnt able to open the tkinter window for me to select any file.

Any advice and comment will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You aren't calling `mainloop`, which is critical for a tkinter application.

Comment: @BryanOakley Even though `mainloop()` is missing, the posted code should still show the `askopenfilename()` dialog with an implicitly created root window.

Comment: Just to confirm, using the exe in the `dist` folder right? Also what's the pyinstaller line of code used.

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes, the exe is in `dist`, for the pyinstaller line of code, do you mean this command? `pyinstaller test.py`

Comment: From the pyinstaller log messages, there are warnings of lib not found, one of it is `_tkinter.pyd`.  So the generated exe should not work.

Comment: Anyway just give `pyinstaller -w -F test.py` a try

Comment: @CoolCloud using `pyinstaller -w -F test.py` there is some error with last few line `File "c:\users\tak\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\scripts\scrapytest\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 358, in cacheDigest
    with open(fnm, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: `

Comment: @acw1668 is it related to the tkinter library? I ran `python -m tkinter` and I can see the interface 'tcl/tk version 8.6`

Comment: Try reinstalling pyinstaller, and also it might be something like acw1668 said too.

Comment: can it be related to the virtual environment, I am not sure if I am doing it correctly, the command I am using 1. `virtualenv scrapytest` 2. `cd scrapytest/Scripts` 3. `activate.bat` then I install the package used in my code like tkinter